# Check if a String is in an ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

How can I check if a `String` is there in the `List`?

I want to assign `1` to `temp` if there is a result, `2` otherwise.

My current code is:

```
Integer temp = 0;
List<String> bankAccNos = new ArrayList<String>();//assume list contains values
String bankAccNo = "abc";
for(String no : bankAccNos)
    if(no.equals(bankAccNo))
        temp = 1;
```

Comment: Why not just set temp to be 2 at the begining? And why use object Integer instead of int? Solution looks good enough if you change what i said

Comment: What you have written already is a working solution, except that you are missing the else statement. Also notice that comparing strings is case sensitive which might be an issue if you didn't get it to work properly. Also, using contains like suggested is another valid approach

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson : yes man i was doin that only but i got confused...
anyway thanks

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
temp = bankAccNos.contains(no) ? 1 : 2;
```

Comment: The `List.contains()` method checks for identity, not equality. It works well for integers but not strings (which is what OP asked for). Iterating over the list, or better, using Java8 List stream is the way to go for `List<String>`

Comment: @Michal the documentation states otherwise https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-
It checks for equality, not identity:
" returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`"

Answer (score 16):

The `List` interface already has this solved.

```
int temp = 2;
if(bankAccNos.contains(bakAccNo)) temp=1;
```

More can be found in the documentation about [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: The `List.contains()` method checks for identity, not equality. It works well for integers but not strings (which is what OP asked for). Iterating over the list, or better, using Java8 List stream is the way to go for `List<String>`

Comment: @Michal Not true as the documentation says otherwise (and I've just tested). Hit the link in my answer and read for yourself.

Comment: `More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).`
So it's equality not identity.

Answer (score 7):

```
    List list1 = new ArrayList();
    list1.add("one");
    list1.add("three");
    list1.add("four");

    List list2 = new ArrayList();
    list2.add("one");
    list2.add("two");
    list2.add("three");
    list2.add("four");
    list2.add("five");


    list2.stream().filter( x -> !list1.contains(x) ).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

The output is:

```
two
five
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*public class Demo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List aList = new ArrayList();
      aList.add("A");
      aList.add("B");
      aList.add("C");
      aList.add("D");
      aList.add("E");
      if(aList.contains("C"))
         System.out.println("The element C is available in the ArrayList");
      else
         System.out.println("The element C is not available in the ArrayList");
      if(aList.contains("H"))
         System.out.println("The element H is available in the ArrayList");
      else
         System.out.println("The element H is not available in the ArrayList");
   }
}*
```

The Output will be:

> The element C is available in the ArrayList The element H is not
> available in the ArrayList