# String inside ArrayList<String[]>

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

How to check whether a specific String is present inside `ArrayList<String[]>`?

Whether I need to iterate each item and check for the string or any specific method for this purpose is present (like **ArrayList.contains()** )?

Tried ArrayList.contains() but not working in my case.

***It is not an `ArrayList <String>` it is `ArrayList<String[]>` so this question is not a duplicate one and am asking this for a curiosity whether any special method is present or not***

Comment: I think you'll have to loop and check. No `deepContains` that I know of.

Comment: Your list is a list of array, are you sure that it is what you want ?

Comment: You'll have to iterate. But this is a fairly inefficient datastructure for doing this.

Comment: contains will check if the string array is present in the arraylist not the string you are trying to find... you will have to loop through the list and go through the array to find the string you want to find

Comment: duplicate Qn [check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208676/check-if-a-string-is-in-an-arraylist-of-strings)

Comment: No guys, it is NOT a duplicate of that Q.  Check the types!!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using ArrayList<String[]> ? Smells like an X-Y-Problem.

Comment: It is not a duplicate one, please check before making this as a duplicate guys (Navas pk and Elliott Sadgamer)

Comment: Just for checking whether any method is present before the iteration method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a example program to get what you asked for... hope it helps

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String []> a = new ArrayList<>();
        String b[] = {"not here","not here2"};
        String c[] = {"not here3","i'm here"};
        a.add(b);
        a.add(c);
        for (String[] array : a) {// This loop is used to iterate through the arraylist
            for (String element : array) {//This loop is used to iterate through the array inside the arraylist
                if(element.equalsIgnoreCase("i'm here")){
                    System.out.println("found");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("match not found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with streams:

```
String contains;
List<String[]> strings;
boolean isPresent = strings.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).anyMatch(contains::equals);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to traverse whole list and then traverse each array inside it to find the item.

```
String valToBeSearched="abc";
for(String [] arr: list)
{
  for(String str: arr)
  {
     if(str.equals(valToBeSearched)){ // do your stuff}
  }
}
```

Comment: @TimCastelijns - there is no `contains` method for array types.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the `ArrayList` with two for-each loops:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] fruit = {"Apple", "Banana"};
    String[] pets = {"Cat", "Dog"};
    arrayList.add(fruit);
    arrayList.add(pets);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayList.toArray())); //[[Apple, Banana], [Cat, Dog]]
    System.out.println(arrayListContains(arrayList, "Apple")); //true
    System.out.println(arrayListContains(arrayList, "Orange")); //false
  }

  public static boolean arrayListContains(ArrayList<String[]> arrayList, String str) {
    for (String[] array : arrayList) {
      for (String s : array) {
        if(str.equals(s)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FNqb/2)

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 streams, you can do this:

```
public boolean containsString(List<String[]> list, String s) {
           // Gives you a Stream<String[]>.
    return list.stream()
               // Maps each String[] to Stream<String> (giving you a 
               // Stream<Stream<String>>), and then flattens it to Stream<String>.
               .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
               // Checks if any element is equal to the input.
               .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at Guava [Iterables.concat()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html).

It can be used to flatten Iterable of Iterables, i'm not sure it will work on an Iterable of Array but it's just a little transformation...
If you can flatten your list, you could then use the "contains" method on the result.