# How to check if a string equals any elements in a previously defined string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I created an `ArrayList` of common passwords I retrieved from the internet and initialized an array called `commonPasswords`. I want to check to see if the user inputted password matches any of the passwords in the array. However, this does not seem to work. I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I just started learning how to program, so I am quite a novice in the field. Thanks!

```
int commonpass = 0;
int check = 0;
while (commonpass == 0) {
    if (password.equals(commonPasswords.get(check))) {
        score = 0;
    }
    check++;
    if (check >= commonPasswords.size()) {
        commonpass++;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `commonPasswords.contains(password)` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a String is in an ArrayList of Strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208676/check-if-a-string-is-in-an-arraylist-of-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`List#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) instead, like

```
if(commonPasswords.contains(password)){
    System.out.println("Password is not safe");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 8 you can do it as below

```
List<String> commonPasswords = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
return commonPasswords.stream().anyMatch(str -> str.equals(password));
```

Comment: you're over complicating things here. Don't just use a lambda because you have to, use it when it makes sense. Nothing beats a simple `contains` here

Comment: You could also do `.anyMatch(password::equals);`

Answer (score 2):

As Chandler has said, you should use `commonPasswords.contains(str)` instead of `password.equals(commonPasswords.get(check))`

```
if commonPasswords.contains(password)
    return true;
```

Or

```
return commonPasswords.contains(passwords);
```

Comment: `contains` already has a loop. No need to add it again. Just increases the complexity

Comment: Oh, yeah, I don't know what I was thinking.  Fixed.

Comment: you could just do `return commonPasswords.contains(password)`

Comment: Yeah, you can, but he's new to programming, and the if statement is more intuitive I think.

Comment: no, its not intuitive. It is bad practice. It seems intuitive to beginners, to compare Strings with `==`. but that's wrong.

Comment: Yes, it seems intuitive to compare Strings like that, but that's wrong because it doesn't work.  `==` compares the object, `.equals()` compares the actual Strings.  This works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are beginner I wrote the following code for you demonstrating 4 possible very simple ways of doing what you desire.
Using Java 8 Stream API and Lambda expressions is not recommended to beginners.

```
    List<String> commonPasswords = Arrays.asList("touraj", "ttt", "toraj", "123");
    String userPassword = "123";

    //First Way:
    if (commonPasswords. contains(userPassword)) {
        System.out.println("Password Found");
    } else
    {
        System.out.println("Password Not Found");
    }

    //Second Way: foreach :: not suggested for beginners
    for (String commonPassword : commonPasswords) {

        if (commonPassword.equals(userPassword)) {
            System.out.println("Password Found");

            // here i use break after finding password to exit loop in order to not wasting cpu
            break;

        }

    }

    //Third Way: simple for loop :: suggested for beginners
    for (int i = 0; i <commonPasswords.size() ; i++) {

        if (commonPasswords.get(i).equals(userPassword)) {
            System.out.println("Password Found");

        }
    }

    //Forth way: Using Java 8 Stream Api :: Not Suggested for beginners like you
    boolean isPassFound =  commonPasswords.stream().anyMatch(pass -> pass.equals(userPassword));
    if (isPassFound) {
        System.out.println("Password Found.");

    }
```

Note: In order to understand java 8 code I suggested here you firstly need to learn object oriented and interface and then learn anonymous methods then learn lambda expressions then learning Stream API...but I think hopefully java 8 version is self-explanatory and similar to human language somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

The OP said he wants to `check to see if the user inputted password matches` so I assume they mean is identical to.

If indeed the OP is looking for identical entries the OP should use `String.equals` and not `Array.contains`. Because `Array.contains` could give him a false positive result.

```
private void checkPasswordExists(){
    List<String> passwordList = Arrays.asList("pass1", "pass2", "pass12", "pass123");

    int countContains = 0;
    String userPassword = "pass1";
    for(String password : passwordList){
        if(password.contains(userPassword)){
            countContains++;
        }
    }

    int countEquals = 0;
    for(String password : passwordList){
        if(password.equals(userPassword)){
            countEquals++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Password countContains = " + countContains);
    System.out.println("Password countEquals = " + countEquals);
}
```

The above code writes to the console:

```
Password countContains = 3
Password countEquals = 1
```